# How to get reduced cost coefficients of the root linear relaxation in CPLEX

Tags: cplex

I am an optimizer and I use the commercial solver ILOG CPLEX (with student license). I would like to know if anyone has managed to obtain the reduced cost coefficients of linear relaxation on the root node. I want to solve an integer linear programming problem, using the CPLEX branch and cut, I want to limit the computation to the root node, and i would like to obtain the reduced cost coefficients calculated there. (maybe you can get them even if you don't limit the computation to the root node). Anyone know how to get them? I'm a python programmer but it's okay if you can do it in another language.

Answer (score 0):

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model
from docplex.mp.relax_linear import LinearRelaxer

def make_bus_model():
    mdl = Model(name='buses')
    nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
    nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')

    mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40 * 40 + nbbus30 * 30 >= 300, 'kids')
    mdl.minimize(nbbus40 * 500 + nbbus30 * 400)
    return mdl

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bm1 = make_bus_model()
    bm1.print_information()
    s1 = bm1.solve(log_output=True)
    s1.display()

    bmr = LinearRelaxer.make_relaxed_model(bm1)
    bmr.print_information()
    rs = bmr.solve(log_output=True)
    rs.display()

    duals = bmr.get_constraint_by_name("kids").dual_value

    print("dual of the 300 kids constraint = ",duals)

    for v in bmr.iter_continuous_vars():
       print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
       rc=v.reduced_cost
       print("reduced cost =",rc)
```

from https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoorelaxintegrity.py

gives

```
objective: 3750.000
nbBus40 = 7.500
dual of the 300 kids constraint =  12.5
nbBus40  =  7.5
reduced cost = 0
nbBus30  =  0
reduced cost = 25.0
```